# CSS Animation from right to left dynamically

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The problem I'm facing is:

- I have a animated text which goes from right to left, this text change depending on the languague set, what is causing that the total width of the text changes too.

[image: Working fine]

In this picture, the effect I want is working fine, because some properties are fixed.

[image]

Now, when I change for a longer text the problem cames up.

So, this is what I have now:

[image]

And this is what I'd like to have:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

**ReactJS Side:**

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    checked: false
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (event.srcElement.body.scrollTop >= 1400) {
      this.setState({ checked: true });
    }
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ... stuff
      <span style={{ fontSize: "40px", color: this.state.theme.COLOR_3 }}>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Resume-chk" style={{ display: "none" }} checked={this.state.checked} />
        <b id="Resume-title">{this.state.languageSet.RESUME}</b>
      </span>
      ... more stuff
    <div>
  );
}
```

**CSS Side:**

```css
//This is the text
#Resume-title {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;

  -webkit-transition: right 500ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: right 500ms ease-in;
  transition: right 500ms ease-in;

  position: relative;
  right: -40.5%;
}

//This is the text when the checkbox is checked
#Resume-chk:checked ~ #Resume-title {
  right: 40.5%;
}
```

So, the question is: **How to fix it?** Or maybe there is some concept I'm missing and it is a little bit more than just fixing a bug.

Also I'm not sure if doing things like `right: -40.5%;` and `right: 40.5%;` is a good practice, but I cant find a way to animate property like `float` or `align`.

Of course, if there is a way to fix it, but also there is a way to do it even better, It is also welcome!!!

EDITED: [here](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/XpMyar) the fiddle containing the whole html section, copied from dev console

Comment: Can you take the actual HTML from the Dev Console and add it to the question? That would be more helpful though you've sort of given the tag details etc already.

Comment: Done!! I've added the whole HTML, you can look for that particular section as #resume. Thanks

Comment: I was actually trying already with whatever tag details that were already there. The **what I'd like to have** is going to be tricky because at one side text is right aligned and when transition is complete, it is left aligned. I am not sure if that is possible but I'll try and post an answer if I manage to find one.

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly the problem I'm facing, I need a transition from one margin to the other one, but also I need to change the aligment. I'd be like a combination between `float` and `text-align`.

Comment: Nice question by the way. Helped me learn something new too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a combination of positioning with **right** and a transform.

This is an usual idea for centering an element, adapted to your request:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: -100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: right 1s, transform 1s;
}

.container:hover .item {
  right: 0%;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>  
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="item">Item long</div>
</div><div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item longer longer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very clever! Nice answer @vals. Have come to expect such innovative answers from you :) I don't know who conceptualized this approach but I am going to call it the **vals'** approach going forward!

Comment: @Harry Thank you !!

Comment: @vals It was very very clever man, and It has worked perfect!!! Thanks. You have won 15+10 points!