# How to create slide animation for JavaScript's HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my project many elements are created through JavaScript.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Akash11166666/pen/JjRzqzp

You can see some quotes with copy button below - just click them once. There will be a custom copy alert that the text is "COPIED!". But the custom alert just pops and vanishes. Is there any way so that they slide in from left to right and vanish?

I know it is easy, but the elements are created from JavaScript, so it is difficult for me.

```js
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const btnJump = document.querySelector('.jump-btn');
const pageValue = document.querySelector('.value-page');

const main = async() => {
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnJump.addEventListener('click', navJump);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.classList.add("allStatus");
  const quotes = paged.map((record) => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.status}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button><span class="status-copy-alert hidden" id="status-copy-alert">Copied!</span></div></div>`);
  const quoteGroupNumer = Math.ceil(quotes.length / 2);
  const groups = Array(quoteGroupNumer).fill('').map((value, index) => {
    const groupQuoteFirst = quotes[2 * index]; // 0, 2, 4, 6
    const groupQuoteSecond = quotes[2 * index + 1] || ''; // 1, 3, 5, 7

    return `<div class="flex">${groupQuoteFirst}${groupQuoteSecond}</div>`;
  });

  contents.innerHTML = groups.join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navJump = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageNoCurr.textContent = pageValue.value;
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {
  return [{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
  ];
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {
      const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')
        .childNodes[0].textContent;
      const notify = e.target.nextSibling.closest('.status-copy-alert');
      notify.classList.toggle('hidden');
      setTimeout(() => {
        notify.classList.add('hidden');
      }, 600);
      const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
      textArea.value = quote;
      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.select();
      document.execCommand('Copy');
      textArea.remove();
    }
  },
  false
);
main();
```

```css
/* Main Status */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #18b495;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

.status-copy-alert {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #18b495;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-weight: 500;
  visibility: visible;
}

.status-copy-alert:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #18b495;
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 39%;
}
```

```html
<a href="hindinj.html">caeman</a>
<div class="mainStatus">
  <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
  <div class="allquotes"></div>
  <div class="pagable-status">
    <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
    <div class="pagable-actions">
      <button class="page-btn-prev btn">PRE</button>
      <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
      <button class="page-btn-next btn">NEXT</button>

      <select name="page-size">
        <option>5</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input class="value-page" />
    <button class="jump-btn">Go</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have made you a snippet. It is very big. Why don't you cut it down to just two elements and remove the rest? You need to start by finding how to animate something from right to left and then apply that transition to the element where you now toggle hidden class. Just toggle an animatedClass and have a right  to left transition in there

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768526/css-animation-from-right-to-left-dynamically

Comment: Sorry, but am new to Javascript and stackoverflow. Can you please explain it to me with my code and answer it. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

**【EDIT】using css transition**

```js
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button><span class="status-copy-alert hidden" id="status-copy-alert">Copied</span>
</div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {

  // write your asynchronous fetching here

  return [{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
  ];
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(

  'click',

  function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();


    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {

      const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')

        .childNodes[0].textContent;

      const notify = e.target.nextSibling.closest('.status-copy-alert');
      notify.classList.add('animatedClass')
      setTimeout(() => {
        notify.classList.remove('animatedClass')
      }, 1000);

      const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

      textArea.value = quote;

      document.body.appendChild(textArea);

      textArea.select();

      document.execCommand('Copy');

      textArea.remove();

    }

  },

  false

);
main();
```

```css
/* Main Status */

.hidden {
  /*   display:none; */
}

.mainStatus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.statusHeading {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #18b495;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.latestatus {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 445px;
  min-height: 130px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.allStatus {
  display: flex;
}

.latestatus p {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.copystatus {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #18b495;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

.status-copy-alert {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #18b495;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: -42px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-weight: 500;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: left 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
}

.animatedClass {
  left: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.status-copy-alert:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #18b495;
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 39%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainStatus">
  <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
  <div class="allquotes"></div>
  <div class="pagable-status">
    <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
    <div class="pagable-actions">
      <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
      <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
      <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
      <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
      <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
      <select name="page-size">
        <option>5</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using jQuery**
Would you like to try jquery?
replace

```
const notify = e.target.nextSibling.closest('.status-copy-alert');
notify.classList.toggle('hidden');
setTimeout(() => {
    notify.classList.add('hidden');
}, 600);
```

with

```
const notify = e.target.nextSibling.closest('.status-copy-alert');
$(notify).removeClass('hidden')
$(notify).animate({
    'left': '8px',
    'opacity': '1'
}, 400, ()=> {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        $(notify).addClass('hidden')
        $(notify).css({
            'left': '-42px',
            'opacity': '0'
        })
    }, 600)
})
```

and also in your css
replace

```
.status-copy-alert {
    ...
    left: 8px; 
}
```

with

```
.status-copy-alert {
    ...
    left: -42px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why jQuery. There is nothing here jQuery solves. CSS can do the transition you use jQuery for with a transition or translate

Comment: No it's not working. Although if you know the answer can you please use Javascript instead of jQuery.

Comment: As recommended by @mplungjan, you can create a new class `animatedClass`, see [this](https://codepen.io/elbbkmbo/pen/KKgOgQm)

Comment: I would also change the delegation so one could click the complete button and not just the text